# iirf {REQUEST_FILENAME} issue

Tags: mod-rewrite, iirf

I have the following iirf rules for my web application

```
RewriteFilterPriority HIGH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f                           
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.cfm?path=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\?(.*)$ /index.cfm?path=$1&$2 [L]
```

Everything works, except when there is a file that exists but has a parameter. 
eg. http://www.domain.com/file.cfm works
    http://www.domain.com/file.cfm?var=foo doesn't work? it skips and redirects to index.cfm

how do i fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that problem.  What version of IIRF are you using?

The `RewriteFilterPriority` directive is no longer supported in the iirf.ini file. Which makes me think you are using an old v1.x version of IIRF.  If so, you should upgrade to v2.x.

Comment: it's 4 IsapiRewrite4.dll did not know about the priority.